# system call in python

Tags: python, system-calls, os.system

i want to make a system call in my python code but the problem is that it breaks the sequence of my original code..

for ex.

```
def call_host(self):
    self.builder.get_object("windowMain").show()         
    os.system('python Adder.py')
    self.builder.get_object("window1").show()
```

in above pygtk code once Adder.py is called next line wont execute i want system to execute adder.py and come back to my original code...
thnx in advance

Here is my code for Adder.py

```
import sys
try:  
    import pygtk  
    pygtk.require("2.0")  
except:  
    pass  
try:  
    import gtk  
except:  
    print("GTK Not Availible")
    sys.exit(1)

class adder:
    result = 0

    def __init__( self, number1, number2 ):    
        return None            

    def giveResult( self,number1,number2 ):    
        self.result = int( number1 ) + int( number2 )    
        return str(self.result)

class adderGui:    
    def __init__( self ):    
        self.builder = gtk.Builder()    
        self.builder.add_from_file("Adder.glade")

        dic = { 
            "on_buttonQuit_clicked" : self.quit,    
            "on_buttonAdd_clicked" : self.add,    
            "on_windowMain_destroy" : self.quit,    
        }

        self.builder.connect_signals( dic )

    def add(self, widget):    
        entry1 = self.builder.get_object ("entry1")    
        entry2 = self.builder.get_object ("entry2")

        try:    
            thistime = adder( entry1.get_text(), entry2.get_text() )
        except ValueError:    
            self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").show()    
            self.builder.get_object("entryResult").set_text("ERROR")    
            return 0

        self.builder.get_object("hboxWarning").show()

        #self.builder.get_object("image1").hide()

        self.builder.get_object("entryResult").set_text(
            thistime.giveResult(entry1.get_text(), entry2.get_text())
        )

    def quit(self, widget):    
        sys.exit(0)

adderGui = adderGui()    
gtk.main()
```

Comment: why the code of Adder.py is important? couldn't it be any script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `subprocess.Popen`, your main program will continue running without "blocking" until the subprocess terminates.

Answer (score 1):

`os.system` will run a command in a subprocess and wait for it to finish before running.  If you want to run it in parallel with the parent process, then you should look at the `subprocess` module -- in particular, you'll want to create a `subprocess.Popen` object.